# PHP and MySQL - REPLACE INTO if NULL on a specific column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to use REPLACE INTO to change the value of column only if it is NULL.

Here is part of the code:

```
  // Set query  
  $this->db->query('REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES (:id, :access, :data, :identifier)');

  // Bind data
  $this->db->bind(':id', $id);
  $this->db->bind(':access', $access);  
  $this->db->bind(':data', $data);
  $this->db->bind(':identifier', $rnd_id);
```

It's part of PDO, so I'm binding the variables along the way to help protect against SQL injection.

I want to only replace 'identifier' only if the column is NULL, but I'm not sure what the SQL query should be.

**EDIT**
Just to provide a bit more information.  The current code above is used to create a sessions table, with the session id, the last time the session was accessed, the session data and a unique identifier. The identifier will eventually be used for the client cookie.

When the query is executed, the session row gets updated. The id remains the same, access and data are updated.
I need a way to update id/access/data as it stands, but only update the identifier if it is null.

The above code is based on this tutorial:
http://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/

Which I am trying to adapt.

Here is everything I have so far:

**database.class.php**
This provides the PDO connections and functions

```
<?php
class Database{
    private $host      = DB_HOST;
    private $user      = DB_USER;
    private $pass      = DB_PASSWORD;
    private $dbname    = DB_NAME;
    private $stmt;

    private $dbh;
    private $error;

    public function __construct(){
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        // Set options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try{
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
        // Catch any errors
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function query($query){
       $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
       if (is_null($type)) {
           switch (true) {
               case is_int($value):
                   $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                   break;
               case is_bool($value):
                   $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                   break;
               case is_null($value):
                   $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                   break;
               default:
                   $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
           }
       }
       $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
   }

   public function execute(){
      return $this->stmt->execute();
   }

   public function resultset(){
      $this->execute();
      return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }

   public function single(){
       $this->execute();
       return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }

   public function rowCount(){
       return $this->stmt->rowCount();
   }

   public function lastInsertId(){
       return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
   }

   public function beginTransaction(){
      return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
   }

   public function endTransaction(){
       return $this->dbh->commit();
   }

   public function cancelTransaction(){
       return $this->dbh->rollBack();
   }

   public function close(){
       return $this->dbh=NULL;
   }
}
?>
```

**session.php**
This code replaces PHP default session handling and saves the data to a sessions table with the columns id (session id), access (time when last accessed) and data (session data).

```
include_once('database.class.php');


class Session {

  /**
   * Db Object
   */
  private $db;




public function __construct(){
  // Instantiate new Database object

  $this->db = new Database;

  // Set handler to overide SESSION
  session_set_save_handler(
    array($this, "_open"),
    array($this, "_close"),
    array($this, "_read"),
    array($this, "_write"),
    array($this, "_destroy"),
    array($this, "_gc")
  );

  // Start the session
  session_start();
}



/**
 * Open
 */
public function _open(){
  // If successful
  if($this->db){
    // Return True
    return true;
  }
  // Return False
  return false;
}

/**
 * Close
 */
public function _close(){
  // Close the database connection
  // If successful
  if($this->db->close()){
    // Return True
    return true;
  }
  // Return False
  return false;
}

/**
 * Read
 */
public function _read($id){
  // Set query
  $this->db->query('SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = :id');

  // Bind the Id
  $this->db->bind(':id', $id);

  // Attempt execution
  // If successful
  if($this->db->execute()){
    // Save returned row
    $row = $this->db->single();
    // Return the data
    return $row['data'];
  }else{
    // Return an empty string
    return '';
  }
}

/**
 * Write
 */
public function _write($id, $data){

   //set the random id length 
   $random_id_length = 10; 

   //generate a random id encrypt it and store it in $rnd_id 
   $rnd_id = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1)); 

   //to remove any slashes that might have come 
   $rnd_id = strip_tags(stripslashes($rnd_id)); 

   //Removing any . or / and reversing the string 
   $rnd_id = str_replace(".","",$rnd_id); 
   $rnd_id = strrev(str_replace("/","",$rnd_id)); 

   //finally I take the first 10 characters from the $rnd_id 
   $rnd_id = substr($rnd_id,0,$random_id_length);   


  // Create time stamp
  $access = time();

  // Set query  
  $this->db->query('REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES (:id, :access, :data, :identifier)');


  // Bind data
  $this->db->bind(':id', $id);
  $this->db->bind(':access', $access);  
  $this->db->bind(':data', $data);
  $this->db->bind(':identifier', $rnd_id);

  // Attempt Execution
  // If successful
  if($this->db->execute()){
    // Return True
    return true;
  }

  // Return False
  return false;
}

/**
 * Destroy
 */
public function _destroy($id){
  // Set query
  $this->db->query('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = :id');

  // Bind data
  $this->db->bind(':id', $id);

  // Attempt execution
  // If successful
  if($this->db->execute()){
    // Return True
    return true;
  }

  // Return False
  return false;
} 

/**
 * Garbage Collection
 */
public function _gc($max){
  // Calculate what is to be deemed old
  $old = time() - $max;

  // Set query
  $this->db->query('DELETE * FROM sessions WHERE access < :old');

  // Bind data
  $this->db->bind(':old', $old);

  // Attempt execution
  if($this->db->execute()){
    // Return True
    return true;
  }

  // Return False
  return false;
}
}
?>
```

I have added a new column 'identifier' to the table. I've also added `$rnd_id` to the `_write` function. This generates a 10 character unique identifier.

When the query `$this->db->query('REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES (:id, :access, :data, :identifier)');` is run for the first time, I can see a new row in the database with all 4 columns filled as expected.
The problem comes on subsequent executions - Though the :id remains the same, the identifier is updated with a new 10 character code.  I want to prevent this from happening and to only add the code in that first time.  Subsequent executions should leave the identifier as it is, or replace it with the same value.

Comment: Use this syntax: `update \`table_name\` set \`column_name\` = 'value'`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
UPDATE sessions
    set id = :id,
        access = :access,
        data = :data,
        identifier = :identifier
    where identifier is null and id = :id;
```

EDIT:

I think what you want is `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into sessions(id, access, data, identifier)
    select :id, :access, :data, :identifier
    on duplicate key update access = :access, data = :data;
```

You need to be sure that `id` is either a primary or unique key.  You can do this as:

```
create unique index idx_sessions_id on sessions(id);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Not quite If I'm understanding your code correctly (I'm a noob). I still need the other three columns to update regardless of the value of identifier.

Comment: @iltdev . . . Edit your question to describe what you want to do.  Sample data and the results that you want are usually the clearest way to communicate this.

Comment: Hi @Gordon. Thanks for your suggestion. I've expanded on the original question to include my code in full. Let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score -1):

You can always update the columns `access` and `data` and update `identifier` if it is `NULL` with a select and [`coalesce`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
replace into sessions
select :id, :access, :data, coalesce(identifier, :identifier)
from sessions
where id = :id
```

Although, this breaks, if there is no existing row with the given `id`. If you need to insert the values, when there is no such row, you must do an insert, if the replace fails.

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/619c6/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Olaf. I want to update the other three columns with value each time it is executed. However, I only want to set the value of identifier if it is null.